# Zend 1 - direct link for file without redirect

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, pdf, zend-framework

I'm using Zend 1.12 for a project and I want to display PDF in the content of the page. Solutions exist with embed, object or the library PDF.js but I always have the same problem : I need to write the path to the file.

And the problem is that the link for the PDF always redirect to an other page because of Zend and I don't know how to make a exception to the folder which contains the pdf files.

Do I have to write some code in index.php, a helper or in the .htacess. I would like your opinion on that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store the PDF on the server or in a /tmp/ folder.

Once you have the PDF file location, you can use the Zend_PDF object to load the PDF like so:

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('/tmp/yourfile.pdf');
```

You can then store it in your view like so:

```
 $this->view->pdf = $pdf;
```

And in your view file, you can use the render() function:

```
$this->pdf->render();
```

Comment: I get the binary content of my pdf I think, it show many characters on the page but how do you use render() to show a view of the pdf ? (my tests was with embded, object or PDF.js).